# Creating Schema Agnostic Backups in BigQuery / Creating Table from JSON type through query

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery, schema, database-backups

Edit: Thanks to @NickW I was shown that with the [Native Snapshot function of BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-snapshots-scheduled) the whole question becomes irrelevant ... it is better avoid reinventing the weel but use what is supported by the framework insted! I'm happy with the solution.

I have the following problem:
I want to create backups that are schema-agnostic, meaning, if the schema (of my raw data) is changed it doesn't fry up my backups.

My idea was to store it into a JSON file, and then query it, like this (in BigQuery SQL):

```
WITH aggregated_table as (
  -- Aggregate all data into one JSON file
  SELECT id ,TO_JSON(row_struct) AS data
  -- Extract each row as a STRUCT
  FROM mytable row_struct)

-- Backups use time as primary key
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as backup_time, id, data from aggregated_table
```

The only issue is that the recovery of the backups is really tedious and I haven't found a way to make it recognize the schema, or at least the column names by itself.

In my case the table has 300+ columns and I don't want to specify every single one like this:

```
SELECT
  backup_time,
  data.id as id,
  TIMESTAMP(data.some_time_value) as some_time_value,
  TIM(data.some_string_value, ") as some_string_value,
  --...300 more columns ...
FROM my_backup WHERE backup_time = xxx
```

I have looked at the JSON documentations on BigQuery for a long time, but I couldn't find the functionality that fits my case ...

Does anyone have a solution? Maybe working with JSON files like this is an antipattern and there is another way to do it?

Many thanks!

I expected a function like flatten JSON that basically reverses my packing I did for the backup. I know the Pandas library in Python can fill table from JSONs but I want to find a way to do it in BigQuery SQL.

Comment: Hi - I'm wondering why you are trying to design your own backup process rather than using one of the processes available out-of-the-box (table export, snapshots, etc)?

Comment: Thanks @NickW , sorry I am such a stackoverflow noob that I don't even know how to give you credits for your reply, nor how to close my question (maybe because you didn't write it as an answer?) ... 
I did use the (before rather intimitadting) snapshot feature and it worked well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment converted to answer…

Instead of rolling your own solution, I would start with one of the processes available out-of-the-box (table export, snapshots, etc)